# How to share files between Windows7(Guest) and Ubuntu 12.04(Host)?

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, vmware, sharing

I searched on the internet but all issues have Ubuntu as the Guest. I have VMWare Workstation 8 wherein Windows 7 is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use folder sharing.

Just go to the settings of your windows VM, select the Options Tab and there you can specify your shared folder as you see on my screenshot (VMware 8, Ubuntu 12.04 Host, Win7 Guest).

[image]

Works flawless for me.

Comment: Never thought it would be this easy, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

mount the windows partition -> users folder then there should be your folder and guest folder and anything else.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get anything else to work, setup a "host only" adapter on VMware and for guest OS. Then set them to be in the same IP range, i.e., guest could have 172.1.1.1/255.255.255.0 and host could have 172.1.1.2/255.255.255.0.

Then try to ping from one to the other, if it works you're in. Then from the Ubuntu 12.04, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type

```
smb://172.1.1.1/c$
```

and then <kbd>enter</kbd> to connect. Put 172.1.1.1 as the domain and the windows user/pass.