# Sharing of files between Ubuntu 14.04 and VMware Windows 7

Tags: vmware, file-sharing

I am unable to share files between Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (HOST) and Windows 7 (VMWare Guest). I tried all the possible options of defining the shared folders in VMWare as mentioned in their site and all sorts. Solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: VMware is a company, which product are you using exactly?

Comment: Did you have a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/129064/how-to-share-files-between-windows7guest-and-ubuntu-12-04host)?

Comment: I haven't seen the link. I will try once and give an update on the same.